# Trying to add variable value from an html form into javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've got a form set up below which has two inputs Keywords and min price

```
<form name="Data" method="GET" action="#">
<table cellpadding="2" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Keywords</th>
    <th>Min Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords"/></td>

    <td><input type="text" name="MinPrice" id="MinPrice"/></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><INPUT type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Then the results obtained need to go into a javascript that then should return result based on the variable. The JS works without the variable i.e. just putting them in in the code, but i can t figure out how to reference the above form then submit the code as a whole

```
      html.push('</tbody></table>');
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = html.join("");
}  
var filterarray = [
  {"name":"MaxPrice",
   "value":"1000",
    "name":"MinPrice",
   "value":Variable here!!,
   "paramName":"Currency",
   "paramValue":"GBP"},
```

Above is part of the script where one of the values would go

Any help apreciated p.s. complete novice so take it very slowly

Comment: Where this result come from? Hidden input field?

Comment: `document.getElementById('MinPrice').value`?

Comment: results come from the top form which when submitted activates the js query

Answer (score 0):

Your list of options is not correct, several properties have the same name.

Here is a different way to present it:

```
var maxPrice = document.getElementById('MaxPrice').value;
var minPrice = document.getElementById('MinPrice').value;
var filterOptions = {
    "MaxPrice": maxPrice,
    "MinPrice": minPrice,
    "paramName":"Currency",
    "paramValue":"GBP"
};
```

You can then use them in your code. For example the min price will be `filterOptions.MinPrice`.

Comment: the other way is how the API requests it to be sent, also this doesnt work

Comment: @JamesAllen to get further help, you'll need to be more specific - for example show the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the content from the MinPrice input text just do the following:

```
var minPrice = document.getElementById('MinPrice').value;
```

or more simply with jquery:

```
var minPrice = $('#MinPrice').val();
```

As for the way you are buiding up your array taht does not make much sense to me:

```
var filterarray = [
  {"name":"MaxPrice",
   "value":"1000",
    "name":"MinPrice",
   "value":Variable here!!,
   "paramName":"Currency",
   "paramValue":"GBP"},
...
```

Here you are building an array of objects containg the same fields multiple times (name and value). That does not make much sense to me. You should maybe reconsider the structure of the literal objects you are trying to populate the array with.